# Give the conditions on the $m\times1$ vector so that a matrix $H$ is orthogonal

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

Give the conditions on the $m\times 1$ vector $x$ such that the matrix $H=I_m-2xx'$ is orthogonal.

The only solution I have found and verified is $x$ could be the zero vector; however, I know there should be more than just this one solution.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of orthogonal matrix $H$ is $HH^T=I$

$$
I=(I-2xx^T)(I-2xx^T)^T=(I-2xx^T)(I-2xx^T) = I-4xx^T+4xx^Txx^T = \\I-4xx^T+4x(x^Tx)x^T =
I+4(x^Tx-1)xx^T.
$$

So either $xx^T=0$ (solution that you have found), or $x^Tx=|x|^2=1$, which means length of vector $x$ is unity.

Comment: How does $(I-2xx')'=(I-2xx')$?

Comment: $(I-2xx')'=I'-2(xx')' = I - 2 (x')'(x)'=I-2xx'$

Comment: Oh, that is much more straightforward than my work. Thank you for your help, Vasily!

Answer (score 0):

I presume $x'$ is the transpose of $x$. Then $H$ is symmetric, so it's 
also orthogonal
iff $H^2=I$. But
$$H^2=(I-2xx')^2=I-4xx'+4xx'xx'=I-4(1-a)xx'$$
where $a=x'x$ is a scalar. So the matrix $H$ is orthogonal iff $a=1$.

Comment: I can see visually that since $x'$ is the transpose of $x$, $H$ would be symmetric, but how can I prove that on paper?

Comment: @MikelSchwob Recall that $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$...

Comment: Additionally, is the condition that $x'x=1$ sufficient to answer this question? Or should I take this a step further by saying that $x$ is a unit vector?